# file_get_contents: failed to open stream: Host is down

Tags: php

I am running php5 on my mac osx 10.5.  If I write a simple php script:

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
?>
```

And run it in the command line, I get the following error:

"Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com): failed to open stream: Host is down"

I'm not sure if I'm missing some setting in php.ini or something. I know if I run the same script off of my server, it executes w/o warning.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewall or you aren't connected to the internet (or maybe you are running something like LittleSnitch which is blocking Terminal.app's access).

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` is set to `On`.  Use `phpinfo()` to check all settings.